# Find the number of five-digit numbers in the notation of which the numbers $89$ and $56$ simultaneously participate

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of five-digit numbers in the notation of which the numbers $89$ and $56$ simultaneously participate.

I am not sure I translated the problem clearly so here are some examples of such numbers: $\color{red}{89}1\color{red}{56},\color{red}{89}3\color{red}{56},\color{red}{89}\color{red}{56}4,7\color{red}{89}\color{red}{56}.$ The given answer is $58$ so I guess **we cannot repeat the digits**. I was thinking about looking at $89$ and $56$ as two units, but I am not sure how exactly we can do that.

Comment: The answer of 58 does include numbers with repeated digits, like 88956 or 56989.

Comment: Commenting an alternative approach, rather than answering, because saulspatz answer is elegant.  Consider $(89), (X), (56)$ as three units, where the 3 units can be permuted in $(3!)$ ways, and where $(X) \in \{0,1,2,\cdots, 9\}$.  This leads to $(3!) \times (10)$, from which you have to explicitly exclude the two specific cases where the leftmost digit is $(0)$.

Comment: @user2661923, thank you for the response! May I ask you if the unit $(X)$ actually consists of $1$ digit, whereas the units $(89)$ and $(56)$ consist of two? How can we see that we have to explicitly exclude the two specific cases where the leftmost digit is $0$ (except for saulspatz' approach)?

Comment: Yes,exactly....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $89$ precedes $56$.  Then the number is of one of the forms $$8956\_\\89\_56\\\_8956$$ There are $10$ possibilities for each of the first $2$ forms, and $9$ for the third, since a five-digit number can't start with $0$.  There are an additional $29$ possibilities when $56$ comes first.